# Qlik sense Desktop License

Tags: qliksense

Can anyone please explain what Tokens, Users, Licenses means in Qlik Sense Desktop? In my QMC it says Unallocated 28% and 30 total token so what does this mean?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming? This just sounds like a company FAQ question.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate). This question is more suitable for [Qlik Community](https://community.qlik.com/) website where you can find [this](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-7151) post/video

*(QS Desktop don't have any users or licenses so i presume you are speaking for QS Server)*

Basically you are buying tokens. Each token can be either `User token` or `Session token`

- `User token` - personalized. 1 token = 1 user. The user have unlimited usage (no time limit). The `user tokens` are usually given to developers and heavy usage users
- `Session token` - 1 token = 10 hours (per month) usage. `Session token` can be split across multiple users. Once the `session token` users consumed 10 hours of content the next token from the pool is allocated.

In your case you have 30 tokens in total. And some of them are allocated (being user or session tokens) and 28% have left un-allocated (8 tokens).